# Движение по контуру фигуры Unity2d

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Делаю 2д игру для андроид. Суть такова: у меня есть шарик (г. г.), который должен двигаться с постоянной скоростью по контуру объекта. Объект в свою очередь это геометрическая фигура как минимум с 3 углами. Никак не выходит движение по контуру этой фигуры, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: выставь теги нормально что бы тебе смогли помочь. Юнити не поддерживает java. А если ты программируешь на джаве, то не подходят тэги c# и Unity. Выставление всех подряд тэгов только отобьет желание тебе помогать. Ибо разбиратся в том что у тебя там за каша никто не захочет.

Comment: Что подразумевается под движением по контуру? Что не получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

самый простой способ из -- Нарисуй сплайн вокруг нужной фигуры и двигай обьект с постоянной скоростью по этому сплайну.

Примеры работы со сплайнами и в т.ч. движение по них можно найти вот [здесь](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/) ( SplineWalker ).

Или скачть готовый ассет который реализует поддержку движения по сплайнам.

Или заглянуть на [википедию с рецептами для юнити](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Hermite_Spline_Controller) и воспользоватся скриптом под это заточенным ( Hermite Spline Controller )

Или нагуглить любой ассет с таковой возможностью. В теории таких должно быть предостаточно.

Comment: Ну это комментарий-ссылка, а не ответ.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я написал словами ответ. Иногда так делают. И без кода. Ссылка - лишь довесок что бы человек не гуглил сам. Можно вообще пойти другим путем и скачать готовый ассет для этого.

Comment: И тем не менее лично я думаю, что этот ответ неполноценен.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker а если учесть что не факт что это решение подходит автору т.к. он дал слишком мало информации по своему вопросу.... то ответ стоит вопроса :) А то сейчас выяснится что что-то не подходит и время на ответ потрачено будет зря. Здесь вообще среди тэгов была java, что б ты понимал. Сейчас кину решение на шарпе, а потом окажется что "ой".

Comment: Так а какой смысл тогда вообще отвечать? Дело то конечно ваше, но звучит все не очень логично.